# Append directories inside a Zip in nodejs

Tags: node.js, zip, fs

I'm trying to add a entry directory inside a zip with **node-archiver**.

When I add only a **file** it's like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var archiver = require('archiver');

var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/example-output.zip');
var archive = archiver('zip');

output.on('close', function() {
  console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
});

archive.on('error', function(err) {
  throw err;
});

archive.pipe(output);

var file1 = __dirname + '/fixtures/file1.txt';

archive
  .append(fs.createReadStream(file1), { name: 'file1.txt' })
  .finalize();
```

And works really well... But If I want to add a directory I don't know how to do it.

ps. Yes, I can zip the entry directory and later add like a file, and then unzip... But isn't a good solution

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the `bulk` option.  Here's a modified example [from the archiver docs](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/blob/8034a5218491a3b3acced1c1b4c8b8adc920f81b/examples/pack-bulk.js).  the cwd is the context root and the src is the glob pattern. `**` will pull all files as an example.  Since it's basically just streams you can chain them together like my example below.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var archiver = require('archiver');

var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/bulk-output.zip');
var archive = archiver('zip');

output.on('close', function () {
    console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
    console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
});

archive.on('error', function (err) {
    throw err;
});

archive.pipe(output);

archive
    .append(fs.createReadStream('./file1.txt'), {name: 'file1.txt'})
    //append more files here
    .bulk([{
        expand: true,
        cwd: './',
        src: ['**/*.js']    //src takes an array of directory glob patterns, can specify multiple entries here
    }]);

archive.finalize();
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. Isn't that I want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue, with ncp package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp and then archiver, it's more easy that I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no point appending emtpy category.

Second, `archive.append(source, EntryData)`. The name in EntryData explained 'Sets the entry name including internal path.' allow you to add path .

For example : './test/file1.txt'.